# json to excel, values of top keys should be in once cell each

Tags: microsoft-excel, json

I am looking for a non copy-paste way to convert a json file to an excel table, such that I am having the top keys in one column, and the rest in another column. Now the "rest" might be a single value, or another nested structure. Regardless, the "values" should be in a single cell each.

Example:

```
"fsGroup": {
    "ranges": [
        {
        "max": 65535,
        "min": 1,
        "type": "/v3/schemas/idRange"
        }
    ],
    "rule": "MustRunAs",
    "type": "/v3/schemas/fsGroupStrategyOptions"
},
"hostIPC": false,
```

This should look like
[image]

I have created this example manually, I would like to have a way to import the json into excel and have it show up like this.

Comment: You have a problem with the second screenshot.

Comment: What is the problem? it shows 4 cells, the way I want them formatted. Its surely not the worlds most beautiful snip ...